# Minor alignment issue in the duplicate search bar

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-suggestions

When close a question as duplicate, in the duplicate search bar, the border right is not visible.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Border right issue]

GIF for the same:

> [image: Border right issue]

**System configurations:**
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox 62.0.3 (64-bit)
Zoom 100%

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Browser and OS configuration, please?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog System information added